# How to copy MS Excel Worksheet into datatable in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I have a Excel Sheet that i need to copy into Data table and later insert into Mysql Database table.I am trying to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.here is the codes that i have tried.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable dataTable = sheet.ExportDataTable();
```

But i dont know how to import sheet from the directory.I am trying these things in Windows Form Application.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you asking how to expose the worksheets once you have the workbook reference?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to open an existing Excel file from the file system, [here's a link to a CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C) on how to manipulate Excel files using C#.  This snippet of code is right on the article's page showing how to open an existing Excel spreadsheet:

```
string workbookPath = "c:/SomeWorkBook.xls";
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

As you can see, you have to use the `Application` object's `Workbooks` property to open the `Workbook` and add it to the `Workbooks` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook_members.aspx).[Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet_members.aspx)[0] (each of those links to the msdn reference).  I don't see a direct way to pull that into a `DataTable`, but you could iterate through the Rows(of class [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members.aspx)) member and simply add to your `DataTable` that way.  From a DataTable it would then be trivial to generate a query using any of the MySQL libraries.